Azure DevOps Pipeline Agent.ToolsDirectory error on self-hosted agent LINUX- RHEL 9 while setting up python under Tool Cache
I have a self-hosted agent that has Python3.9.18 installed which comes as part of RHEL 9 Image. Everytime I run the pipeline I get an error.
##[error]Version spec 3.9 for architecture x64 did not match any version in Agent.ToolsDirectory.
Versions in /home/<user>/myagent/_work/_tool:
<BLANK>

I have created the folder structure as well
/myagent/_work/_tool/Python/3.9/x64/<tool files> and x64.complete but still no success it doesn't find anything underneath "Agent.ToolsDirectory"
environment variable has been set.
echo $Agent.ToolsDirectory
/home/<user>/myagent/_work/_tool

Could you recommend some options to consider?
What needs to be done for the tool files? What are these files?
Tried options :

I tried by keeping unzipped python 3.9.18 tar files but no success

I tried creating a simlink to point _tool to /usr/bin/python where my base python is installed.

Referred this link  and tried setting venv but dnf was not able find and install the package.

Whenever I tried installing the python to this new _tool directory it just says python already installed.


I am trying to use this task UsePythonVersion@0.

I tested in my self-hosted agent. I can reproduce the issue when I use the version 3.9 in the path.
In the official document How can I configure a self-hosted agent to use this task?, it mentions that

The version number should follow the format of 1.2.3.
As a complete and concrete example, here is how a completed download of Python 3.11.4 for x64 would look in the tool cache:

$AGENT_TOOLSDIRECTORY/
    Python/
        3.11.4/
           x64/
               {tool files}
           x64.complete

So, you should change the /myagent/_work/_tool/Python/3.9/x64/<tool files> to /myagent/_work/_tool/Python/3.9.18/x64/<tool files>.
Update:
You can download the python package version you need in the python-versions releases page or python-versions tags page and unzip it as the {tool files}.
For example:

The x64.complete file is not in the x64 folder.
You can also use the following yaml to check the python files in the Microsoft hosted agent.
pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- task: UsePythonVersion@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '3.9' 
    architecture: 'x64' 
- bash: tree  $(Agent.ToolsDirectory)/Python/3.9.19
- task: CopyFiles@2
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: '$(Agent.ToolsDirectory)/Python/3.9.19'
    Contents: '**'
    TargetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    ArtifactName: 'drop'
    publishLocation: 'Container'

The published artifact content:


Also I am not understanding what are the tool files should be. Currently i have place the unzipped python files by doing tar -xvf python3.9.18. Also,, while trying the troubleshoot i installed python3.9 again so i found a file under /usr/local/bin called python3.9 so i have placed that too. Can you please let me know what are the tool files referred to here.

Hi @Lbits, I have updated the answer with what are the tool files should be. Please check the update of the answer. Thanks!

But still there is no success still my pipeline is throwing me with exact same issue. I have even restarted the machine and stopped and started the svc.sh service but still no success.
Versions in /home/ipldevopsadmin/myagent/_work/_tool: 

Hi @Lbits, the x64.complete file is not in the x64 folder. They are both under the version number folder. I replaced the screenshot in the answer to make it clearer. Please check. Thanks!

Hi @Miao Tian-MSFT, I realized an issue with the installation though I have created all file structure based on documentation and kept files from "https://github.com/actions/python-versions/releases" so the pipeline was able to find the tools

Hi @Miao Tian-MSFT, I realized an issue with the installation though I have created all file structure based on documentation and kept files from "https://github.com/actions/python-versions/releases" so the pipeline was able to find the tools
Found tool in cache: Python 3.10.14 x64
Prepending PATH environment variable with directory: myagent/_work/_tool/Python/3.10.14/x64 but on the next step during install requirements its again going to local system python and referring that.

ERROR : Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable.
Requirement already satisfied: pip in /home//.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages

Hi @Lbits, I noticed that you have created a new question for the error and there is an answer for it. Please try that answer, thanks!
